# Widget Transparency in PyGTK?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk, cairo

What is the best way to have transparency of specific widgets in a PyGTK application? I do not want to use themes because the transparency of each of the widgets will be changing through animation.

The only thing I can find is to use cairo to draw widgets with an Alpha, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there perhaps a better way to do this as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your program runs under composition manager, you could get per-widget transparency by manipulating widget's X window. Look at [gtk.gdk.Window.set_opacity()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--set-opacity).

Note, it is not `gtk.Window`; you can get this object by getting its `window` property (`buttonWidget.window`), but only when widget is realized and only when widget does handle events -- gtk.Label does not have its own X window for instance.

If you need to work also when you don't have composition manager, drawing your widgets by yourself is the only option -- but you don't necessarily have to use cairo; drawing pixel by pixel on the bare X window will also work.